# R: How to estimate the parameters of a Gamma distribution, knowing the empirical cumulative distribution

Tags: r, gamma-distribution, fitting

I have been given an empirical cumulative distribution, and I need to fit a Gamma distribution to it using R.

By trial-and-error (and using Excel's Solver), I know that's possible, but I need to automate this process (I need to update this distribution each week, so automation is needed); I'd like to do it in R, so I can use the results in some other reports (using `sweave` for example).

Data sample:

```
           F
0  0.0000000
1  0.4761905
2  0.5665025
3  0.6284307
4  0.6851982
5  0.7404266
6  0.7994206
7  0.7994206
8  0.8595944
9  0.8595944
10 0.8595944
```

Best estimate (so far): `Gamma` distribution with the following parameters: `alpha = 0.357779` and `theta = 12.019887`

Comment: How exactly are you defining "best"?  Once you have a working definition (two possibilities might be in terms of Kolmogorov distance or a Cramer von Mises criterion) you may be able to use the `optim` function in R to optimize your objective function over the parameters of the gamma distribution.

Comment: @dsaxton it's the best fit under minimum square error (defined as the sum of the squares of the difference between theoretical and "empirical" functions) and Kolmogorov distance

Comment: Using maximum likelihood on the raw data (if that's available) would be a more standard approach.  But if you only have the "binned" data, then maximum likelihood can still be used but you'd need to construct the likelihood accounting for the binned data.  And that is easily programmed with the use of `optim` as suggested by @dsaxton.  And you'd need to be able to specify the sample size.

Comment: But if you have the empirical cumulative distribution function, why isn't the maximum value 1.0?

Comment: actually I have the empirical survival function... In this particular example, `Pr{X > 10} = 0.14` (approximately)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the observations only take on integer values, then while a gamma distribution might be a reasonable summary function, you don't really have an underlying gamma distribution.

However, if the integers were just used to bin the data, then you can determine the maximum likelihood estimates of the two gamma distribution parameters in the following manner.  I've made the assumption that you have the sample size available and for this example I used $n=235$.

```
# Available sample cumulative distribution function
  x <- c(0:10,Inf)
  f <- c(0.0000000,0.4761905,0.5665025,0.6284307,0.6851982,0.7404266,0.7994206, 
    0.7994206,0.8595944,0.8595944,0.8595944,1)

# Determine counts in each bin assuming that the total sample size is 235
  counts <- diff(floor(235*f+0.5))
  counts

# Define log likelihood function for the binned data
logL <- function(p) {
  s <- 0
  for (i in 1:(length(counts)-1)) {
      s <- s + counts[i]*log(pgamma(x[i+1],p[1],1/p[2])-pgamma(x[i],p[1],1/p[2]))
  }
  s <- s + counts[length(counts)]*log(1-pgamma(x[length(counts)-1],p[1],1/p[2]))
  s
}

# Find maximum likelihood solution (with starting values from other method)
  solution <- optim(c(0.357779,12.019887), logL, method="L-BFGS-B",
    lower=c(0.001,0.001), upper=c(Inf,Inf), control=list(fnscale=-1))
  solution
#  $par
#[1]  0.3370922 12.3350379
#
#$value
#[1] -412.9522
# 
#$counts
#function gradient 
#     17       17 
#
#$convergence
#[1] 0
#
#$message
#[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"

# Plot results
  plot(c(0:10), f[1:11], type="s", xlab="x", ylab="Probability")
  lines(c(0:100)/10, pgamma(c(0:100)/10,solution$par[1],1/solution$par[2]), col="red")
```

[image: cumulative distribution function fit]

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, the data comes from an estimation of the survival function of a given population (I don't have the raw data, only the survival function estimate at the given points). I'll try this approach.